# SCCM Software Update Installation Issue

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, sccm-2012-r2, sccm-2007

I've deployed a group of Windows updates to a collection which has no maintenance window and it's works correcty and all devices are comliant excep one who do not getting the updates and showing "Client check passed/Active" state.

I've tried to stop wuauserv service and delete "SoftwareDistribution" floder but it isn't works for me.

below details about my environment.

Client Device :  windows Server 2012 R2 whitch hosts the McAfee antivirus solution.

FYI: I've tried to stop McAfee services but it restart automaticaly when the process of updates begin.

SCCM Management Server: SCCM 2012 R2 SP1, WSUS 4.0 (6.3.9600.18694)
Logs :

- WUAHandler.log :  Successfully completed scan
- UpdatesDeployment.log :  EnumerateUpdates for action (UpdateActionInstall) - Total actionable updates = 0
- LocationServices.log : ALL its correct
- WindowsUpdate.log : 4 Warning

WARNING:     IsSessionRemote: WinStationQueryInformationW(WTSIsRemoteSession) failed for session 9, GetLastError=2250
WARNING: Failed to get Wu Exemption info from NLM, assuming not exempt, error = 0x80240037
WARNING: Failed to initialize event uploader for new server {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77} with hr = 8024043d.
WARNING: Network Cost is assumed to be not supported as something failed with trying to get handles to wcmapi.dll

Comment: Have you tried to set antivirus service startup mode to disabled and restart the host?